# Fill in Bellow a group df pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a data frame that I made the transpose of it looking like this

[image]

I would like to know how I can transform this group into filled lines, follow an example below

[image]

Where the first column is filled with the first value until the last empty row.
how can i do this if the column is grouped

Answer (score 0):

In your case, repeat the indices of your data frame five times, save them in a new column, and then make the column entries original indices.

```
ibov_transpose['index'] = ibov_transpose.index.repeat(5)
ibov_transpose.set_index('index')
del(ibov_transpose['index'])
```